# How to bind a combination of keys to a method?

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit, key-bindings

How can I bind <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + S</kbd> to a method? Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23377819/tkinter-keybinding-for-control-shift-tab) I tried the below code but it doesn't work(print statement isn't run):

```
import tkinter as tk

def key(event=None):
    print("It works!")

root = tk.Tk()

frame = tk.Frame(root, width=100, height=100)
frame.focus_set()
frame.bind('<Control-Shift-s>', key)
frame.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Also I'd like to know the general answer on how to bind key combinations if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>s</kbd> becomes <kbd>S</kbd>.

Therefore, your bind never triggers. To fix this you can just change your bind to:

```
frame.bind('<Control-Shift-S>', key)
```

Comment: This does work, thanks! I will add also `frame.bind('<Control-Shift-s>', key)` for it not to be case sensitive, would you happen to know a better way than repeating like that as well?

Comment: Apparently I _do_ need to use two binds according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7402516/tkinter-case-insensitive-bind).